# Formula field on Object not calculated in report

Tags: reporting, formula

I have a number of fields on the `Case` object that are part of a field that is totalled:

```
IF( 

NOT( 

AND( 

Interpreter_Pay__c == null, 
Nurse_Pay_Rate__c == null, 
Interpreter_Hours__c == null, 
Interpreter_Travel_Fee__c == null, 
Site_Fee__c == null, 
Administrative_Fee__c == null 
) 
), 

Interpreter_Pay__c * Interpreter_Hours__c 
+ Nurse_Pay_Rate__c * Interpreter_Hours__c 
+ Site_Fee__c 
+ Administrative_Fee__c 
+ Interpreter_Travel_Fee__c 

,null)
```

The field calculates properly on the case detail page but when generating a report shows `-` on all records . Is there some limitation to salesforce stopping me here or have I missed something?

edit: none of the fields in the formula are formulas themselves; each will be manually entered.

Comment: Did you run the report? In the preview sometimes formula fields do not display the data.

Comment: Running the report returns `-` also

Comment: Are you running the report as an admin? Is it possible to have permission issues?

Comment: I am an admin of the org, incredibly unlikely to be a privilege issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF( 
AND(
 ISNULL(Interpreter_Pay__c), 
 ISNULL(Nurse_Pay_Rate__c), 
 ISNULL(Interpreter_Hours__c), 
 ISNULL(Interpreter_Travel_Fee__c), 
 ISNULL(Site_Fee__c), 
 ISNULL(Administrative_Fee__c)
),
NULL,
Interpreter_Pay__c * Interpreter_Hours__c 
+ Nurse_Pay_Rate__c * Interpreter_Hours__c 
+ Site_Fee__c 
+ Administrative_Fee__c 
+ Interpreter_Travel_Fee__c 
)`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! Would you mind explaining the difference to me and why the original formula would work on detail page but not in report?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was not working for you, it might be related to how SF is treating some validations: they have ISNULL() formula that supposed to be used for any null or blank values validations